# Difference between normed plt.xcorr at 0-lag and np.corrcoef

Tags: python, numpy, correlation, cross-correlation

I am working on a cross correlation between two relatively small time series, but in trying to accomplish I am running into a problem I cannot reconcile myself. To begin, I understand the dependence between `plt.xcorr` and `np.correlate`. However, I am having trouble reconciling the difference between `plt.xcorr` at zero lag and `np.corrcoef`?

```
a = np.array([  7.35846410e+08,   8.96271634e+08,   6.16249222e+08,
     8.00739868e+08,   1.06116376e+09,   9.05690167e+08,
     6.31383600e+08])
b = np.array([  1.95621617e+09,   2.06263134e+09,   2.27717015e+09,
     2.27281916e+09,   2.71090116e+09,   2.84676385e+09,
     3.19578883e+09])

np.corrcoef(a,b)
# returns:
array([[ 1.        ,  0.02099573],
      [ 0.02099573,  1.        ]])

plt.xcorr(a,b,normed=True, maxlags=1)
# returns:
array([-1,  0,  1]),
 array([ 0.90510941,  0.97024415,  0.79874158])
```

I expected these to return the same result. I clearly do not understand how `plt.xcorr` is normed, could someone please set me straight?

Answer (score 2):

Calculation of standard "Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient" is using samples, shifted by mean values.
Cross-correlation coefficient doesn't use normalized samples.
Other than that, computation is similar. But still those coefficients have different formulas and different meaning. They are equal only if mean values of samples `a` and `b` are equal to `0` (if shifting by mean values doesn't change the samples.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([7.35846410e+08, 8.96271634e+08, 6.16249222e+08,
     8.00739868e+08, 1.06116376e+09, 9.05690167e+08, 6.31383600e+08])
b = np.array([1.95621617e+09, 2.06263134e+09, 2.27717015e+09,
     2.27281916e+09, 2.71090116e+09, 2.84676385e+09, 3.19578883e+09])

y = np.corrcoef(a, b)
z = plt.xcorr(a, b, normed=True, maxlags=1)
print("Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient between `a` and `b`:", y[0][1])
print("Cross-correlation coefficient between `a` and `b` with 0-lag:", z[1][1], "\n")


# Calculate manually:

def pearson(a, b):
    # Length.
    n = len(a)

    # Means.
    ma = sum(a) / n
    mb = sum(b) / n

    # Shifted samples.
    _ama = a - ma
    _bmb = b - mb

    # Standard deviations.
    sa = np.sqrt(np.dot(_ama, _ama) / n)
    sb = np.sqrt(np.dot(_bmb, _bmb) / n)

    # Covariation.
    cov = np.dot(_ama, _bmb) / n

    # Final formula.
    # Note: division by `n` in deviations and covariation cancel out each other in
    #       final formula and could be ignored.
    return cov / (sa * sb)

def cross0lag(a, b):
    return np.dot(a, b) / np.sqrt(np.dot(a, a) * np.dot(b, b))

pearson_coeff = pearson(a, b)
cross_coeff = cross0lag(a, b)

print("Manually calculated coefficients:")
print("  Pearson =", pearson_coeff)
print("  Cross   =", cross_coeff, "\n")


# Normalized samples:
am0 = a - sum(a) / len(a)
bm0 = b - sum(b) / len(b)
pearson_coeff = pearson(am0, bm0)
cross_coeff = cross0lag(am0, bm0)
print("Coefficients for samples with means = 0:")
print("  Pearson =", pearson_coeff)
print("  Cross   =", cross_coeff)
```

**Output:**

```
Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient between `a` and `b`: 0.020995727082
Cross-correlation coefficient between `a` and `b` with 0-lag: 0.970244146831 

Manually calculated coefficients:
  Pearson = 0.020995727082
  Cross   = 0.970244146831 

Coefficients for samples with means = 0:
  Pearson = 0.020995727082
  Cross   = 0.020995727082
```

Comment: But I thought the purpose of the `normed=True` argument to `plt.xcorr()` was to normalize the input vectors... How is "normalize the input vectors" for `plt.xcorr` different from the normalization done before calculating Pearson r?

Answer (score 0):

I used http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xcorr

> normed : boolean, optional, default: True
>
> if True, normalize the data by the autocorrelation at the 0-th lag.

In the following code, `plt_corr` equals `np_corr`.

```
plt_corr = plt.xcorr(a, b, normed=True, maxlags=6)

c = np.correlate(a, a)  # autocorrelation of a
d = np.correlate(b, b)  # autocorrelation of b
np_corr = np.correlate(a/np.sqrt(c), b/np.sqrt(d), 'full')
```

Answer (score 0):

As DJV's answer says, on `plt.xcorr`, `normed=True` normalizes only the magnitudes. If you also want to normalize to mean=0, as is done for the Pearson r, you can add the argument `detrend=mlab.detrend_mean`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

plt.xcorr(a, b, normed=True, maxlags=1, detrend=mlab.detrend_mean)
```